# How to catch exception when write to a random memory block in c++

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks

```
int main()
{
    int *a; // a = 0x4053c6 (a random address)
    // this will cause the program to exit, and how do i know this memory can't be written ?
    *a = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Confused! I mean does this snippet always lead the program to crash ? And is there a case that this program can execute from begin to end?

Comment: You have to keep track of it yourself. In this case you know `a` is uninitialized, so reading that pointer value is undefined behavior (let alone writing to its deferenced location).

Comment: I know `a` is uninitialized. And most compliers will report a warning. However, I want to know is there a chance for `*a = 5` to execute.

Comment: @Ggicci: yes, there's a chance - undefined behaviour means anything can happen. If could be that by some wild coincidence, `a` holds e.g. its own address and `*a` is therefore a valid place to write to (as far as the OS restricting the program knows). Still, if `a` happens to hold its own address that doesn't guarantee it would work... nothing's guaranteed for undefined behaviour.  There are other harmless possibilities too - e.g. `a` could easily point at some stack space that's not currently in use.

Comment: @TonyD How to write a demo to prove that a chance exists? I tried to use `try-catch` block in c++, but failed. `*a = 5` seems not to throw an exception. So if there is another way to tell, I'll be appreciated very much :)

Comment: @Cgicci - If you write stupid code expect stupid things to happen. Simply write code and ensure that memory leaks do not happen. Use compiler warnings, applications like purify/valgrid and testing.

Comment: @Ggicci: Why would it throw an exception? Like we've been saying, it's *undefined behavior*. You simply cannot and should not try to *define* it.

Comment: @GManNickG, it is not a C++ exception but a trap (SEH). Some systems call these as exceptions (Windows).

Comment: That's a bit like saying "if I flick my fishing line out over the water, is it possible that I accidentally hook an eagle flying past?" yes "tell me how to prove that!".  You can't prove it without either being *incredibly* "lucky" or falsifying the results (e.g. by setting an initial value of a in a debugger, showing it's safe in a function other than the top of `main` where you've had the change to can manipulate the stack content): just not practical or meaningful.  A conceptual understanding of what you're doing must suffice.

Comment: @user1952500: I didn't say it was an exception.

Comment: Yes, but you mentioned "why would it throw an exception". The system raises an SEH exception. I was pointing that out.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I never write code like this. And for the reason why I ask such a question is that my teacher said `*a = 5` in such a snippet will always cause a crash in class this morning. But I don't think it's right. So I have to prove.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. Do you really want to antagonize him/her to prove a point?

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, i have a bit obsession, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will usually lead to a crash, but it's not guaranteed (since the variable is uninitialized, it could contain any value, valid or invalid). You can't catch an access violation with C++ exceptions, but compilers provide extensions to do it. For example, with Visual C++, you can use SEH (Structured Exception Handling):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x00000100);

    __try
    {
        *p = 10;
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
    {
        cout << "Access violation" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << *p << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will Segfault / have an access violation which is handled as a trap or a signal depending on the operating system. You may be able to handle it but it is quite unlikely you'll be able to do much afterward. (The usual course of action after handling it is a graceful exit).

As for establishing that there is a case it will be quite tough to prove it. You can have your own compiler that sets uninitialized variables to a particular address on the stack for example (sarcasm).

One way to pseudo-initialize the value in a is to call a function:

```
void func(int k)
{
    int *a;
    int b = 0;
    if (k == 1) {
        a = &b;
    }
    *a = 5;
}
```

You can try with func(1) a few times and then try func(2). There is a **chance** that a and b will reuse the same stack area and not fail. But again this is also a **chance**.